# How can I control the duration of a song?

Tags: super-mario-maker

So for boss battles I like to play the Boss Music ([example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S2MiapKBWis)), but the Music only plays for a short while then stops. What's more, the length of time it plays for is inconsistent. I'm not sure if this is just an oversight in the game, or if I'm doing something wrong.

How can I control the duration of a song in Super Mario Maker?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to be controlled by distance from the tile.

However, if you have multiple music tiles, the music will continue playing (without the starting effect) as long as you're within 1/2 to 2/3 of the screen from the last one you touched.

Note: For boss music, you can attach the music to the boss themselves.  As long as the enemy is within range and not dead, the music will play.

Since bosses tend to follow you, this works pretty well.

Answer (score 4):

If you attach the mini-boss music to an enemy (say, Boswer Jr. or a Hammer Bro.) it will continue playing until that enemy is dead.

This is the opposite behaviour of the other sound effects that play when the enemy dies.

For the sake of completion: You can also attach music to Mario, and it will play throughout the level.

Answer (score 0):

So through some experimenting it appears that you can't really control the length of music, but you can control an area it plays in. Essentially, if Mario hits a tile  which plays music, then that music will continue to play so long as he continues to touch tiles with that music block in it. The music will eventually stop playing once Mario has stopped touching a tile containing that music block.

So if you wanted to have a room that played music for the duration of Marios stay you would need to put a Music block in every tile of the room. Aside from being annoying, this does have the flaw that there is a limit the number of music tiles you can have in a level, and it's not very large.

Something else I've discovered,and which the [internet confirms](https://www.reddit.com/r/MarioMaker/comments/3kuzxb/psa_you_can_make_a_music_sound_battle_or_bonus), is that putting a music tile on Mario will make a song play for the duration of the level.

Comment: Neither of these solutions are perfect, so I'm hoping there's some additional solutions I've missed.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, if ya just stick it on an enemy, it'll play as long as the enemy is ALIVE. If you beat the enemy the music stops. What I do is encase a Goomba in hardblocks and attach the music to him. The goomba won't die and as long as the goomba is on the screen the music plays forever. If you want music to play forever no matter where Mario goes, either attach the music to Mario or put musical goombas throughout the stage.

Comment: You kind of contradict yourself.  You say that as long as the Goomba is alive, the music will play, but you also say as long as they are on the screen.  So what happens if you move too far away from the Goomba?